# How should I store my oscilloscope and probes

Tags: oscilloscope, probe, best-practice

What are the best practices for storing an oscilloscope and probes?

Should the probes be disconnected after use, etc.?

Comment: You can get "bnc silicone captive dust covers" which are cheap and easy to not lose, although I don't know if they'd work with those connectors that have pins for additional functionality. Don't forget any other connectors on the back of the scope that you might want to keep dust-free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to store probes is to remove them of the oscilloscope. I saw more then one scope broken from falling due to a probe pulling it off the bench. The other aspect is ESD. Oscilloscope are not the most sensitive to ESD, but they still are. A probe hanging from the oscilloscope extend the reach of an ESD discharge. Finally, a probe laying around on a bench is likely to get damaged (depending what you use the scope for).

How I stored mine is that I always remove all the proves and place them in their carrying case. Then I place ESD cap on all the exposed ports. It prevent ESD discharge but the main reason I'm doing it is to prevent dust from getting inside the ports. In a previous work, we had hangers for probe. I don't see any issue with that technique except that all the accessories for the probes were lost. The carrying case has the advantage of keeping everything at reach.

The coaxial cable in an oscilloscope probe is somewhat fragile. Rolling the cable over the probe makes a too short bending radius, so don't do that!

Answer (score 3):

I think it's better to remove them from the BNC connectors because damage to the connector is less likely (less leverage). Some oscilloscopes have covers that go over the entire front of the instrument and which will protect the screen, knobs, switches and BNC connectors (particularly important if the latter have a thin shell that is plastic rather than just easily bent metal), and those should be used.

But better not to store it away at all, an oscilloscope is an everyday tool and it's good to have a place reserved for it.

Comment: Mine hang over the end of the bench when not being used. I put the clips on them to protect the pins.

Answer (score 2):

Another point not mentioned: disconnect the oscilloscope from AC mains if not using for a while (any gear tbh). Just keep in mind that some tools might have internal batteries which might need ocasional powering to keep settings, etc.

I've had tools lost due to lightning strikes while some others were safe because they were unplugged.

Comment: Unplugging to protect from lightning is not ideal since many older test instrument have old batteries that holds some memory. Unplugging it might get you loose your cal factors inside your instruments. A better solution is to place a surge protector on your lab. They are inexpensive and very efficient.  The best solution is to install a UPS.

Comment: An other advice, in that same line of thought is every instrument with an hard drive should be cloned before the drive fails. I keep a backup drive for all my drive plus a ghost image of the drive whenever I buy a test instrument. You can't imagine how hard they are to recreate if you don't have the original at hand!

Comment: @Julien - I had surge protectors and UPS on my lab when it suffered the lightning strike. I've had different scales of damage - complete loss, some ports not working, etc. The absolute safe gear were the ones that were unplugged.

Comment: Good point about the batteries though, I rarely keeps things unplugged for more than a few days at a time so it didnt come to mind when writing the answer.